# Change executable path of a program

Tags: path, zathura

While I was trying to install mupdf backend for Zathura, I accidentally did `pip install zathura` (in user mode) as Meson build kept complaining about a missing dependency, and now the executable path for zathura is now `~/.local/bin/zathura` instead of `/usr/bin/zathura`. I tried uninstalling the wrong program with `pip` (as well as uninstall/reinstall the correct zathura package), but it still complains about the wrong executable path.

It's possible to set it back using an alias (e.g. `alias zathura="/usr/bin/zathura"`), but I'd rather not do that unless that's exactly how it works behind the scenes. Is there another way to change the executable path?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the variant of the program that you installed with `pip`? `pip uninstall zathura` should do that.  This is assuming that you actually have a pre-existing `/usr/bin/zathura` installed by some other means. (Note that I don't actually know what this program is)

Comment: Yup, I uninstalled the wrong program using `pip`, but it's still on the wrong executable path. I guess I should probably update the post to make that a little bit more clear.

Comment: Stuff gets installed in `~/.local` by `pip` if you use it with its `--user` option. Did you do that? If so, did you try uninstalling with the `--user` option too?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I'll probably update the post to be a bit more clear about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a symlink to `/home/user/.local/bin/zathura` via

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/.local/bin/zathura /usr/bin/zathura
```

Or, you could copy the file directly using

```
sudo cp /home/user/.local/bin/zathura /usr/bin/zathura
```

I don't know how well this will work with the specific program you're using, but has always worked for me at least when I invoke that program as the user it was installed with via `pip`

You will also need to change the `user` in the paths provided.